# ViewBag in another action is null

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this code:

```
public PartialViewResult studentsDiv(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                id = ViewBag.studentId;
            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.studentId = id;
            }

            ACD_UNI_STUDENTS students = db.ACD_UNI_STUDENTS.Find(id);

            return PartialView(students);
        }

        public PartialViewResult personalStudentDetails()
        {
            int? id = int.Parse(ViewBag.studentId);
            ACD_UNI_STUDENTS students = db.ACD_UNI_STUDENTS.Find(id);

            return PartialView(students);
        }
```

but it throws an exception in `int? id = int.Parse(ViewBag.studentId);` it says that my viewbag is null. But it's actually not null because in first time it anyway goes in my *studentsDiv*  action. When I'm debugging id is there for example 1 but on my *personalStudentDetails* this ViewBag is anyway null

and here's my view:

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Full details", "studentsDiv", new
        {

        }, new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            UpdateTargetId = "studentsDiv",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
        }, new { @class = "sactive", id = Model.ID })
|
@Ajax.ActionLink("Partial details", "personalStudentDetails", new
        {

        }, new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            UpdateTargetId = "studentsDiv",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
        }, new { @class = "sactive", id = Model.ID })
```

Comment: `ViewBag` is for passing a value from a controller method to its view. Ass soon as the view is rendered, its disposed so its `null`

Comment: thanks @StephenMuecke . Another what can i try?

Comment: I can't actually see where your using the `ViewBag` property in the views anyway so not sure what the point of it is. Why do you not just pass the `id` as a route parameter in the `ActionLink()` methods and then use `public PartialViewResult personalStudentDetails(int id)`?

Comment: @StephenMuecke actually i want this id in action not in view. in personalStudentDetails(int id) this id goes null

Comment: That's because you never pass a value for `id` to the method. I'm guessing your assuming that `new { @class = "sactive", id = Model.ID }` does it, but thats adding the html `id="##"` attribute to the `<a>` tag (not adding a route parameter for `id`)

Comment: @StephenMuecke than how can I do that? can u give me an example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your ActionLink() methods to pass the `id` as a route parameter to your methods (ditto for `personalStudentDetails`)

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Full details", "studentsDiv", 
    new { id = Model.ID }, 
    new AjaxOptions()
    {
        HttpMethod = "GET",
        UpdateTargetId = "studentsDiv",
        InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
    },
    new { @class = "sactive" }) // assume you don't really need an id attribute
```

Then the methods can be (assuming the ID property is not nullable)

```
public PartialViewResult studentsDiv(int id)
{
    ACD_UNI_STUDENTS students = db.ACD_UNI_STUDENTS.Find(id);
    return PartialView(students);
}

 public PartialViewResult personalStudentDetails(int id)
{
    ACD_UNI_STUDENTS students = db.ACD_UNI_STUDENTS.Find(id);
    return PartialView(students);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rectify @Ajax.ActionLink() to

```
@Ajax.ActionLink("Partial details", "personalStudentDetails", new
        {
         id = Model.ID //Here value
        }, new AjaxOptions()
        {
            HttpMethod = "GET",
            UpdateTargetId = "studentsDiv",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace
        }, new { @class = "sactive" })
```